# Create PEM keypair in javascript readable by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cryptography, rsa, jwt

Usecase: client creates RSA keypair in browser, sends pubkey to server and then signs his messages using secretkey kept in local storage.

I've looked over JWT but it does not have keypair generation in browser (or I couldn't find it). I have found a library that creates keys (https://github.com/juliangruber/keypair) but I get a pub key that is not readable in PHP from the `openssl_pkey_get_public` function.

I'm really stuck - I thought it was supposed to be pretty common but after a whole day googling I can't understand a thing. Lots of standards, formats...

Can anyone advise a library or method by which I can **create keys at cient in JS and verify message, using pubkey in PHP**?

Here is what I have so far:
I've created pubkey in JS, using library mentioned above

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAM3CosR73CBNcJsLv5E90NsFt6qN1uziQ484gbOoule8leXHFbyIzPQRozgEpSpi
whr6d2/c0CfZHEJ3m5tV0klxfjfM7oqjRMURnH/rmBjcETQ7qzIISZQ/iptJ3p7Gi78X5ZMh
LNtDkUFU9WaGdiEb+SnC39wjErmJSfmGb7i1AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Then I saved it to "/pubKey.pem" file and try to read it with PHP:
`openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("/pubKey.pem"));`

And it fails. I suppose format is not the one that expected?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Its probably not that common a requirement as it seems this is attempting to duplicate what SSL/TLS already does

Comment: Well it's really common when _server_ creates keys.
In my case client should create keys and give the public one to server, so we don't have client's secret - we can just verify his message. It's also common in real life, but trouble is that we have to make keys in browser by js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openssl_pkey_get_public` expects keys to be in the PKCS8 format. eg.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDNwqLEe9wgTXCbC7+RPdDbBbeq
jdbs4kOPOIGzqLpXvJXlxxW8iMz0EaM4BKUqYsIa+ndv3NAn2RxCd5ubVdJJcX43
zO6Ko0TFEZx/65gY3BE0O6syCEmUP4qbSd6exou/F+WTISzbQ5FBVPVmhnYhG/kp
wt/cIxK5iUn5hm+4tQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I was able to convert it with phpseclib:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAM3CosR73CBNcJsLv5E90NsFt6qN1uziQ484gbOoule8leXHFbyIzPQRozgEpSpi
whr6d2/c0CfZHEJ3m5tV0klxfjfM7oqjRMURnH/rmBjcETQ7qzIISZQ/iptJ3p7Gi78X5ZMh
LNtDkUFU9WaGdiEb+SnC39wjErmJSfmGb7i1AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($key);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8);

$res = openssl_pkey_get_public("$rsa");

var_dump($res);
```

Maybe there are other non-CLI solutions for converting PKCS1 keys to PKCS8 but if so I'm unaware of it.